# Prove the following claim

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

Prove the following claim:
$$\int_o^Lsin(\lambda_nx)sin(\lambda_mx) dx =0$$ if $n\ne m$ where both $\lambda_m$ and $\lambda_n$ satisfy the equation $$\lambda_kcos(L\lambda_k)+hsin(L\lambda_k)=0$$

I was able to get the integral down to $$\frac{sin(L(\lambda_n+\lambda_m))}{\lambda_n^2+\lambda_m^2}$$
but I'm not really sure where to go from there. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you expect such a thing to hold!? I think that you are dealing with some Sturm-Liouville problem and trying to prove the orthogonality of eigenfunctions directly! However, I think you have made a mistake in some previous steps!

Answer (score 0):

We have, assuming $m \neq n$ implies $\lambda_n \neq \pm \lambda_m$
\begin{eqnarray*}
I &=& \int_0^L \sin ( \lambda_n x ) \sin (\lambda_m x) \textrm{d} x \\
&=&  - \frac{1}{\lambda_n} \cos ( \lambda_n x ) \sin (\lambda_m x) \big|_{x=0}^{x=L} + \frac{\lambda_m}{\lambda_n} \int_0^L \cos( \lambda_n x ) \cos(\lambda_m x) \textrm{d} x \\
&=&  - \frac{1}{\lambda_n} \cos ( \lambda_n L ) \sin (\lambda_m L) + \frac{\lambda_m}{\lambda_n^2} \sin( \lambda_n x ) \cos(\lambda_m x) \big|_{x=0}^{x=L} + \frac{\lambda_m^2}{\lambda_n^2} I \\
&=&  - \frac{1}{\lambda_n} \cos ( \lambda_n L ) \sin (\lambda_m L) + \frac{\lambda_m}{\lambda_n^2} \sin( \lambda_n L ) \cos(\lambda_m L) + \frac{\lambda_m^2}{\lambda_n^2} I \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now rearranging yields
\begin{eqnarray}
I &=&  \frac{1}{\lambda_n}  \frac{\lambda_n^2}{\lambda_m^2 - \lambda_n^2}\cos ( \lambda_n L ) \sin (\lambda_m L) - \frac{\lambda_m}{\lambda_n^2} \frac{\lambda_n^2}{\lambda_m^2 - \lambda_n^2} \sin( \lambda_n L ) \cos(\lambda_m L) \\
&=& \frac{\lambda_n}{\lambda_m^2 - \lambda_n^2}\cos ( \lambda_n L ) \sin (\lambda_m L) - \frac{\lambda_m}{\lambda_m^2 - \lambda_n^2} \sin( \lambda_n L ) \cos(\lambda_m L) \\
&=& \frac{\lambda_n \cos( \lambda_n L) \sin( \lambda_m L ) - \lambda_m \cos( \lambda_m L) \sin( \lambda_n L)}{\lambda_m^2 - \lambda_n^2}\\
&=&\frac{- h\sin( \lambda_n L) \sin( \lambda_m L ) + h \sin( \lambda_m L) \sin( \lambda_n L)}{\lambda_m^2 - \lambda_n^2}\\
&=&0
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Use it to see where you went wrong :).